# Save workspace/state on Git branch switch

Tags: phpstorm

Using PHPStorm to switch Git branches is great, but it usually throws all of my breakpoints around when there is a large difference between the new branch HEAD and the old one. Is there a way to snapshot what files were open and what lines had breakpoints on them?

When closing PHPStorm and re-opening it, those values are saved. Is there a way to leverage that same information on switching Git branches?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for **Tasks & Contexts** (Tools > Tasks & Contexts > Open Task or Switch Task)
Windows: `Alt`-`Shift`-`N` for Open, and `Alt`-`Shift`-`T` to Switch.

Open Task will allow you to create a new Task. This will prompt you to create a git branch when you create a new Task. This task will be associated with the branch, and will be automatically marked as closed when you commit. By associating the task with a branch, PhpStorm will automatically switch between branches, along with its default task behaviour of closing/opening task-relevant files. This should preserve your breakpoints.